# Two foreign keys reference one table and null able foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am new to Database tables and relationships .I need some help for the below requirements

Work flow

```
    1. Hospital will have Male Patient
    2. Hospital will have Female Patient
    3. Hospital Will have Couple Patient but in RegTable it will stored as separate record for male and female.
```

For the above requirements i have designed the table structure below

**Approach 1**

RegTable

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| RegID |  Name   | Gender  |
+-------+---------+---------+
|     1 | XXX     | M       |
|     2 | XXX     | M       |
|     3 | Husband | M       |
|     4 | Wife    | F       |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

RegDetail

```
+----+------+-------+
| Id | FK_1 | FK_2  |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |    1 | Null  |
|  2 |    2 | Null  |
|  3 |    3 | 4     |
+----+------+-------+
```

FK_1,FK_2 is RegId from Regtable

I have two questions

1. Is my current approach is correct or Not ?
2. Is alternative approach is there for the above work flow .

Kindly help me solve this .  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 tables here.You can do it as shown below.

```
RegTables - this is the only table you need

Id int PK

Name string

Gender String 

PatientType tinyint
```

Here you can maintain `enum Type` for separating `Single` and `couple`.

```
public enum PatientType : byte
    {
        Single=1,
        Couple =2,
    }
```

**Update :**

```
Treatments table

Id int PK

Name string

RegId int FK --> this is the foreign key referencing RegTables table
```

Comment: Thanks Sampath for your answer . But  how i can identify the Male and Female belongs to couple. Like In Reg Detail 3,4 row will be on couple

Comment: By using the `Type` enum. You can save it as `1` if it is a couple.

Comment: +-------+---------+---------+
    | RegID |  Name   | Gender  | Type 
    +-------+---------+---------+
    |     1 | XXX     | M       | 0
    |     2 | XXX     | M       | 0
    |     3 | Husband | M       |1
    |     4 | Wife    | F       |1
    +-------+---------+---------+  Like this Right

Comment: I did small modification above.I think now it's better.`Single` you can save as `1` and `couple` as `2`

Comment: Hi Sampath , the RegTable will contain this Columns right  | RegID | Name | Gender | Type

Comment: Yes,more meaningful if we give it as `PatientType`.I have done that modification on the my post above.Please see that.

Comment: Yes Sampath , you are correct but i have one more workflow also in that case the Couple patient will act as seperate for some treatement. Like **Semen Analysis** its for applicable for only male . But For semen analysis is Applicable for Couple->Male , Male patient. How can create a table for it . I am new to database design.

Comment: Please see the `Update` section above.

Comment: You're warmly welcome ! If you have any db design issues in future please contact me.I'll help to you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the third table `RegRecords` with field 
id, note, date. It will contain a registration data without link to RegTable. So you will store links to real people in `RegDetail` that will have only two fields: FK_KEY_RegRecords and FK_KEY_ RegTable.

Comment: Thanks Andrej . Can you kindly explain on this briefly .

Comment: I am having doubts with RegRecords . With RegRecords how will i get whether the patient is Couple .

Comment: select * from RegDetail group by FK_KEY_RegRecords having count(*) > 1.